# How to select an entire record when a single entry matches

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a case where I need to aggregate data and I have a record nested within each row. What I would like to do is to see if an entry in the record  matches and then return the record in it's entirety since I'm interested in other data there. Here is a basic schema of the data I have

```
|- name
|- age
+- properties (repeated)
|  |- key
|  |- value
```

So a select like this

```
SELECT
    <some-columns>
FROM
    <table>
WHERE
    propeties.key = "candy"
```

Would only return the row where the record has a key that matches "candy" and not "game". Hope this makes my problem clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In BigQuery you can use OMIT RECORD IF clause for that purpose:

```
SELECT
    <some-columns>
FROM
    <table>
OMIT RECORD IF
    EVERY(propeties.key != "candy")
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Are you using SQL ?

What is the real structure of "properties" ?

You should use an inner join to find the "candy".

Then an outer join to match "game" and keep only those which are null.

```
SELECT id, name, age
FROM table
INNER JOIN properties AS p1
ON table.id = p1.table_id AND p1.value = "candy"
LEFT OUTER JOIN properties AS p2
ON table.id = p2.table_id AND p2.value = "game"
WHERE p2.value IS null;
```

I don't know if this works.

With postgresql, sub-select are very efficient :

```
SELECT id, name, age
FROM table
INNER JOIN (SELECT table_id FROM PROPERTIES WHERE value = "candy" ) AS p1
ON table.id = p1.table_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT table_id FROM PROPERTIES WHERE value = "game" ) AS p2
ON table.id = p2.table_id
WHERE p2.table_id IS null;
```

Comment: He is using BigQuery, and the "record" is a special type there, there is no need for join.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Vouze.